# No files in ~\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I have just installed Visual C++ 2010 Express on my laptop (running with Windows8) and I have created a new project (Win32 console Application).

VS 10 generates all the files, and when I build the solution I have the following message

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: toDelete, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>c:\users\arthur\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\todelete\todelete\stdafx.h(10):     fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

According to what I have read in other forums, I should have the file stdio.h (and others) in the directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

It appears that this directory contains only a file srv.h
If my understanding is correct, Visual C++ Redistributable installs such files in this directory. I have reinstalled it without any change!

Could you please confirm that my understanding is correct, ie that the directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

should contains files such as stdio.h and then do you have any idea how to get them???

Many thanks!